# Chrome keyboard shortcut to "close other tabs"?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

In Chrome we can close all the tabs in a window while keeping a selected one open.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to "close other tabs"?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no keyboard shortcut I know of and after checking Google forums, neither does anyone else.

You could use the extension [Close Inactive Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ljigdlkhdinjbdmhdfmoglfcegnnkill?hl=en-GB) instead - This adds a button which closes all other tabs except the active one.

Comment: There's [an entry in the suggestions box](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=066071374cf663d0).

Comment: This extension doesn't work on Mac Chrome 66.

Comment: Link is broken :-(

Comment: Well, they removed the whole option now.

Comment: and added the option again :)

Comment: The extension was removed from the Chrome Web Store for policy violation.

Answer (score 15):

I wrote [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-to-clo/fipfgiejfpcdacpjepkohdlnjonchnal) so that we can assign shortcuts for closing tabs to the right / left / other tabs / pin / unpin tab. Let me know if you can use it.

Update: It's temporarily off from Chrome Store and I'm working to get it back.Meanwhile, you can install it from here:  https://github.com/diophung/close-chrome-tabs

[image: custom shortcuts]

---

Update 2019/06/10:
Still works with Chrome 75
[image: custom shortcuts]

Comment: Your screenshot above shows command-key–based shortcuts, but in the app store it shows option-key–based. Can this be configured? Option key is primarily for typing alternate characters (é, ü, ∞, etc); it shouldn't be used without the command key for commands.

Comment: This extension doesn't work on Mac Chrome 66.

Comment: @jtheletter Chrome 66 move the link to the hamburger icon, and you still can configure the shortcut for it: chrome://extensions/shortcuts . I'll update the extension. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @jtheletter https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-to-clo/fipfgiejfpcdacpjepkohdlnjonchnal : I updated the extension and you can customize the hotkeys using any recognizable key combos.

Comment: It works flawlessly, many thanks for this little add-on!

Comment: I've been busy but let me know if you have any suggestion to improve this add-on

Comment: It now says: "This extension violates the Chrome Web Store policy." What happened?

Comment: @SU3 : No idea, Google said this extension didn't have a privacy policy statement so they removed it. I'm working on restoring it back. Hang on there

Comment: @SU3 :  the extension is back to Chrome Store:  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-to-clo/fipfgiejfpcdacpjepkohdlnjonchnal

Answer (score 4):

The shortcut key to close all other tabs is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> if you install [Amazing Tab Shortcuts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amazing-tab-shortcuts/mecfgphfppeggakljpnmgfaokfcfjkef), freely available in the Chrome Web Store.

I use it frequently for scripts, which I suspect is your use.

Comment: Alas, doesn't appear to work on Linux.

Comment: Wohou is such a combination still called "short"cut?

Answer (score 3):

[Here is an extension that assigns a keyboard shortcut to close other tabs. .](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-to-clo/dkoadhojigekhckndaehenfbhcgfeepl?hl=en)

Works great on my Mac with Chrome stable channel.

Comment: This extension doesn't work on Mac Chrome 66.

Comment: On Mac you can just set a key command to any menu item. You don't need to jump through hoops at all.  New answer added.

Answer (score 2):

None of them work.  The easiest way is to right-click on the tab that you want to keep open and then click 'close other tabs'. The shortcut to close ALL tabs is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, to open a new tab is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and to close the tab you are on is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.  Also, if you close a tab by mistake and want to reopen it to the same page it was on, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.  Experiment with the rest like, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, etc.

Comment: In the question it we can see already that the way how to do this with mouse is known. I think it is not needed to show keyboard shortcuts for other functions here.

Answer (score 2):

In OS X you can create `~/Library/Scripts/Applications/Google Chrome/` and save this script there with Script Editor:

```
tell window 1 of app "google chrome" to close tabs whose id is not (get id of active tab)
```

Then use [FastScripts](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) to give the script a shortcut.

Comment: Hey, this was excellent. Thank you!

Comment: Best answer! I use Keyboard Maestro, just added hot key and set action "Execute AppleScript". Works perfect!

Comment: On Mac you can just set a key command to any menu item. You don't need to jump through hoops at all. New answer added.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en), you can use `Ctrl+X` to close other tabs (add `map <c-x> closeOtherTabs` to Vimium -> Options -> Custom key mappings) and `Shift+X` to restore the last closed tab.

Comment: Thanks Vimium is great!  I'm now using <c-x> but I had to configured that. There was no default shortcut for closeOtherTabs even though the function was there.

Answer (score 2):

#### On Windows

1. Press <kbd>F6</kbd> twice. This will focus the current tab in the tab bar.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>. This is the keyboard shortcut for right click on Windows.
3. Now, you can use the arrow keys to move to the "Close other tabs" and press Enter.

Comment: As a more convenient alternative to `Shift+F10`, most full-keyboards have a dedicated button for opening a context menu (usually somewhere between `Ctrl` and `Alt`.

Answer (score 0):

this script is definitely working :

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome"
    set activeTabId to id of active tab of front window
    repeat with tabIndex from (count of tabs of front window) to 1 by -1
        set aTab to tab tabIndex of front window
        if id of aTab is not equal to activeTabId then
            close aTab
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

I use Afred (on Mac) to activate it.

Comment: On Mac you can just set a key command to any menu item. You don't need to jump through hoops at all.   New answer added.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac you can add a keyboard shortcut to any menu item.
This still works on Ventura, but the location has moved. [Use search in Settings]

[image]

[image]