# Restore old Chrome tab context menu

Tags: google-chrome

Recently, Chrome has switched their context menus to have `Close Tabs to the Right` as an option. I was a big user of `Close Other Tabs`. I find the new option clunky.

Is there a flag or some other magic that I can set to restore the old context menu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome keyboard shortcut to "close other tabs"?](https://superuser.com/questions/298576/chrome-keyboard-shortcut-to-close-other-tabs)

Comment: @CaldeiraG i'm not asking for a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I can confirm [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1182253/880618) works fine on Chrome 78. It's a shortcut, not sure about the context menu itself

Comment: Looks like the feature is [back again](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/17617890?msgid=19965721) on Chrome Dev, wait a few days for it to be released. The topic is very popular at the moment so hopefully it will come back.

Comment: I will confirm if the functionality is present on Chrome Dev, if yes I will write an answer :)

Comment: Hey there, if my answer solved the issue, could you please accept it? (so we can remove this out of Unanswered tab). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The feature [is back again](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/ba3a2b7ea39791e5dc95a5b69ca5d10ab68f32dd) with the new version 78.0.3904.108.

---

### Old answer

The feature got removed on Chrome 78 for some reason but on Chrome Dev 80.0.8970.5 this feature is back again so expect for it to be back in some days.

[image]

As a alternative, you can always use a extension called [Keyboard shortcuts to Close Chrome Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-to-clo/fipfgiejfpcdacpjepkohdlnjonchnal) mentioned on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1182253/880618). The name is self explanatory.